# How do I make my bouncing ball move?

Tags: java, ios, animation, javafx, timeline

So I'm writing a program where the ball bounces around the screen but when i launch it, the ball doesn't move at all. I've used the animation value for Timeline, and dy and dx as my boundaries for radius across the screen.

```
public class BallPane extends Pane {

public final double radius = 5;
public double x = radius, y = radius;
public double dx = 1, dy = 1;
public Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);
public Timeline animation;

public BallPane(){
//sets ball position
x += dx; 
y += dy; 
circle.setCenterX(x); 
circle.setCenterY(y);

circle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
getChildren().add(circle); 

// Create animation for moving the Ball
animation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall() ));
animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
animation.play();
}    

public void play(){
    animation.play();
}

public void pause(){
    animation.pause();
}

public DoubleProperty rateProperty(){
    return animation.rateProperty();
}

public void moveBall(){
// Check Boundaries
    if(x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
        dx *= -1; //change Ball direction
    }
    if(y < radius|| y > getHeight() - radius) {
        dy *= -1; //change Ball direction
    }
}
}
```

This is my launch code:

```
    public class BounceBallControl extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    BallPane ballPane = new BallPane(); // creates the ball pane

    ballPane.setOnMousePressed( e -> ballPane.pause());
    ballPane.setOnMouseReleased( e -> ballPane.play());

    Scene scene = new Scene(ballPane, 300, 250);
    stage.setTitle("BounceBall!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    ballPane.requestFocus();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
   launch(args);
}
```

I took out the increase speed and decrease speed methods cause they seemed irrelevant (incase anyones wondering the speed was set at animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 0.1). why is my ball not moving (at all), it stays in the corner?

Comment: Which code do you think is going to make it move?

Comment: well they're both connected through Inheritance (in netbeans they are in the same package) so I'm using the first code for method implication and the second file is the one that extends to Application and has the main method that launches the program in a whole. So I was using the second one to launch the whole program.

Comment: so I guess the first program would make it move since it has the Timeline animation = new Timeline and moveball() method.

Comment: Huh?  You want the ball to move in the animation, right? There is no code related to the animation that would cause the ball to change position.

Comment: Wow I guess the book I'm reading really sucks it portrays the following code and i've left out the imports cause I figure they aren't needed (there was import javaFX.animation.Timeline, I was thinking that would make it "animate" by the following: animation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall() ));
animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
animation.play();
})
but I see what your saying. I would i go about making the ball move across then? See my goal is a pong game and I've made the paddles with rectangles and achieved them to move up and down with arrows

Comment: if it's too long to type do you have a good link for moving objects in javaFX?

Comment: James_D has a [good link on bouncing balls here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) Narinder.

Comment: That's weird the book says it uses Timeline to animation ball bouncing. which is maybe a lib in JavaFX (I have the most recent version). If you have any other ways for Javafx and Java please show me how to go about or a site that can help. Please and Thank You..

Comment: Seems like I was missing Velocity which is a key component to movement obviously the book did not mention this. thank you jewelsea, and anyone who commented

Comment: WOW I just ran that in netbeans and that is a site to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually [relocating](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html#setCenterX-double-) the ball when you move it.

See the sample below, which re-centers the ball at new x and y co-ordinate locations to move it.

```
public void moveBall() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    // Check Boundaries
    if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
        dx *= -1; //change Ball direction
    }
    if (y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
        dy *= -1; //change Ball direction
    }

    circle.setCenterX(x);
    circle.setCenterY(y);
}
```

Note, you could do away with the separate x and y variables entirely, as their values are already represented via the centerX and centerY properties of the circle, but I've left your x and y variables in the above code so as not to differ too much from your originally coded solution.

Comment: oh see what I had done is I had relocated the circle.setCenterY() and X() at the top of the program did not think it would make a difference, I didn't realize that it was inside the MoveBall() method got to make sure I Check my "{ }" right. so If i wanted to make the ball speed go quicker I would just up my Duration.millis() right? actually nevermind I just realized I'd do that using my increaseSpeed method. thanx

Comment: No, varying the timeline duration would not be a good solution for you (you will either get choppy animation or lack of fine grained, dynamic control of the velocity of your ball unless you use also use interpolated key values). Perhaps you should ask a new question about the best way to vary the velocity of moving your ball.

Comment: Oh i did do an example out of my book a week or two back where it used a ball going around a circle (an ellipse) and it would slow down at the curve so I used setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR); I'm guessing that is what you mean by interpolated key. but a velocity would be more in favour, am I right?

Comment: Narinder, please ask questions as questions, that is how StackOverflow works - it will get you the best answers.

Comment: Oh, I see you already did ask a new question :-) [why main method in Java need to be public always?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297008/how-do-i-make-bouncing-ball-move-quicker-dynamic-velocity/36298346#36298346)